# How can i read excel file using zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, phpexcel

How can I read an xls/xlsx file from a controller using Zend framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net/). Worked great for me.

Comment: throw it into /library/.. and add autoloadernamespaces.1 = "PHPExcel_" to your application.ini

Comment: I have placed the PHPExcel folder downloaded from phpexcel.net and placed in zend library folder and added autoloadernamespace = "PHPExcel_". please help me how to call in controller to read the excel file.

Comment: The documentation archive (current version as of this writing is [v1.7.7](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/downloads/get/381160)), has an `Examples` folder. Hey, gotta do some of the work yourself... ;-)